# Does the SQL statement 'break' make set have no use?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider this [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL):

```
while (@Level<6)
    begin
      if (not exists(select 1 from tbtask where row_guid in (select Row_GUID from Cad_Catalog where CatalogID=@TaskCatalogID)))
         begin
            select @TaskCatalogID=PcatalogID from Cad_Catalog where CatalogID=@TaskCatalogID
            set @isUserCreateCatalog=1
         end
      else
         break
      set @Level=@Level+1
    end
```

When executing `else` and `break`, it still executes.

```
set @Level=@Level+1
```

`break` jump to the while loop!

If it executes `set @Level=@Level+1`????? So I think

```
 set @Level=@Level+1
```

has no use! Is that true?

Comment: It is just when it enter in else statement the break sends it back to the while, all the code after wont execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as Jorge says, as soon as you have said "break" the loop will stop. And thus not updating the @Level variable.

But if you want to break out, then updating the variable shouldn't matter if it's only used in the loop.

If you need the updated level, you can do it like this.

```
else
  begin
     set @Level=@Level+1
     break
  end
  set @Level=@Level+1
end
```

Comment: break not jump out of while loop?

Comment: Yes it jumps out of the loop.